# Error: error inspecting object: no such container minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to run minikube on ubuntu 18.04 version. getting an error while starting minikube. Please help. Tried minikube delete and start again but dosent work

```
Aspire-E5-573G:~$ minikube start --driver=podman --container-runtime=cri-o
  minikube v1.13.0 on Ubuntu 18.04
❗  Using podman 2 is not supported yet. your version is "2.0.6". minikube might not work. use at your own risk.
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.19.0 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v6-v1.19.0-cri-o-overlay-amd64.tar.lz4: 551.13 MiB /
  Restarting existing podman container for "minikube" ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: podman inspect ip minikube: sudo -n podman container inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} minikube: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Error: error inspecting object: no such container minikube

  Restarting existing podman container for "minikube" ...
  Failed to start podman container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: podman inspect ip minikube: sudo -n podman container inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} minikube: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Error: error inspecting object: no such container minikube


❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: podman inspect ip minikube: sudo -n podman container inspect -f  minikube: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Error: error inspecting object: no such container minikube


  If the above advice does not help, please let us know: 
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error already indicates podman 2 is not yet supported.

```
Using podman 2 is not supported yet. your version is "2.0.6". minikube might not work. use at your own risk.
```

The workaround for this as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9120) is to use version v.1.9.3.

Here`s the [merge](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/8784/files/0d78fe56afd08ca789b91b18fc40b18329f63374) that was done to warn about podman version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. I tried using docker as the driver in the arguments and it worked. Podman 2 is not yet supported